# What wrong with this MySql & PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weird problem in mysql with php

I am running this query with PHP's `mysql_query` function.

Assume that view_counter = 30

```
UPDATE cini_gallery_data SET view_counter = view_counter+1 WHERE id = '10'
```

After this query

view_counter is 32 or sometimes 33 instead of 31

I have checked for duplicate queries also.

Whats wrong with this? It's so weird.

EDIT: php code i have used.

```
if(!mysql_query("UPDATE cini_gallery_data SET view_counter = view_counter+1 WHERE id='10'")){
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: -1. how can it be a typo? if it is a typo, it means you are writing the code. **Don't write the code; Always copy/paste**. Who knows what typo you had in the original version which got corrected here. **An answer has got deleted** because your statement _it was a typo_ made it irrelevant.

Comment: maybe you have executed the code multiple times?

Comment: No i did'nt Here is my full src code http://pastebin.com/i5bVA0Jh

Comment: What does mysql_error() display?

Comment: nothing...Actually that query does not rise any errors.. If i execute same query in mysql workbench it's works correctly. But in that src code make this wired. Thanks Jocelyn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you edited your question, and you said that you are not able to increment the counter, I guess you've set your `id` field or `view_counter` on `AUTO INCREMENT`

Previous Answer :

This is wrong

```
WHERE = '10'
```

You forgot to add column name in your `WHERE` clause, It should be

```
WHERE column_name = '10'
```

Comment: I need this to count number of views for a page.. I want to increment view_counter in UPDATE statement

Comment: @RoxSoft as I already told you, you've set your `ID` column on auto increment...take out the auto increment

Comment: how you can increment it to 31 when you are giving a condition for id = '10'

Comment: I have a row which its id is 10 and it's view_counter value is 30 

So i did used "WHERE id=10"